# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find') on redux reducer when setting Favorites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is my `initialState`:

```js
const initialState = {
  products: null,
  product: {
    product_name: null,
    Product_type: null,
    Product_description: null,
    price: null,
    Image_Url: null,
    product_id: null,
  },
  favorites: [],
  cart: null,
  total: null,
};
```

`setFavorite` reducer case:

```js
setFavourite: (state, action) => {
  // Check if the product is already in favorites
  const isAlreadyFavorited = state.favorites.find(
    (favorite) => favorite.product_id === action.payload.product_id
  );

  if (!isAlreadyFavorited) {
    // Create a new favorite object and add it to the favorites array
    const newFavorite = {
      product_id: action.payload.product_id,
      favorite: true,
    };

    // Create a new state object with the updated favorites array
    state.favorites = [...state.favorites, newFavorite];
  }
},
```

`dispatch` function:

```js
onClick={() => dispatch(
  setFavourite({
    product_id: item.product_id,
  })
)}
```

I even tried checking `state.favorite.length === 0` condition, but still I am getting error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find' or "length")".

Comment: Please check value of `state` with `console.log()` in your reducer function, I bet you'll have `favorites` content, not the whole state.

Comment: my state was store in the local store that is why i cannot update it. as i remove my slice name from the whitelist. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure you are initializing your initial state correctly try the below:

Instead of checking `state.favorite.length` try check for the whole `state.favorites` array:

```js
setFavourite: (state, action) => {
  // Initialize favorites as an empty array if it's undefined
  if (!state.favorites) {
    state.favorites = [];
  }

  // Check if the product is already in favorites
  const isAlreadyFavorited = state.favorites.find(
    (favorite) => favorite.product_id === action.payload.product_id
  );

  if (!isAlreadyFavorited) {
    // Create a new favorite object and add it to the favorites array
    const newFavorite = {
      product_id: action.payload.product_id,
      favorite: true,
    };

    // Create a new state object with the updated favorites array
    state.favorites = [...state.favorites, newFavorite];
  }
}
```

However, if you hit this error, your initial state is likely not being set at all for some reason, which I can't say with the code you provided.

Comment: my code just worked and i dont have any idea but in store.js file while creating persistconfig i just removed my slice name and it worked after that. my initialstate was not picking the favoties array due to whitelist but now it is...